# Remove all numeric index to have an assoc array only

Tags: php, arrays

If i have an array like this after issuing a print_r() statement:

```
//print_r($theArray)
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'Animal' => string 'Dog' (length=3)

  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'House' => string 'white house' (length=11)

  2 =>
    array (size=1)
      'Human' =>  
         array (size=3)
           'Africans' => string 'Nigroids' (length=8)
           'Europeans' => string 'Caucasoids' (length=8)
           'Asians' => string 'Mugoloids' (length=8)
```

how can i remove all numeric indices such that above array becomes

```
array(
     'Animal' => string 'Dog' (length=3),
     'House' => string 'white house' (length=11),
     'Human' =>  
         array (size=3)
           'Africans' => string 'Nigroids' (length=8),
           'Europeans' => string 'Caucasoids' (length=8),
           'Asians' => string 'Mugoloids' (length=8)
    )
```

any help is please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One foreach just enough

```
$new = array();
foreach($array as $arr) 
       $new  =  $new + $arr;
 print_r($new);
```

Comment: it all worked. but i went for splash58's method. thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Double `foreach()` would work:

```
<?php
    $array[]    =   array('Animal'=>"dog");
    $array[]    =   array('House'=>"white");
    $array[]    =   array('Human'=>array("Africans"=>"af","Europeans"=>"ca","Asians"=>"as"));

    foreach($array as $arr) {
            foreach($arr as $key => $data) {
                    $new[$key]  =   $data;
                }
        }

    print_r($new);
?>
```

**Gives you:**

```
Array
(
    [Animal] => dog
    [House] => white
    [Human] => Array
        (
            [Africans] => af
            [Europeans] => ca
            [Asians] => as
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as:

```
$theArray = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $theArray);
```

This is equivalent to the following, just with an arbitrary number of arrays:

```
$theArray = array_merge($theArray[0], $theArray[1], $theArray[2], ...);
```

---

Alternatively, for some functional fun:

```
$theArray = array_reduce($theArray, 'array_merge', []);
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($theArray as $array) {
    $result = array_merge($result, $array);
}
$theArray = $result;
```

Comment: i thought about Array_reduce but solved that faster avoid function call

Comment: be carreful with array_merge, in case of same keys only the last one is kept

Comment: @Hanane The alternative would be what…? If you have that situation, then you need to define what should happen to duplicate keys, and implement another solution accordingly.